# How to copy an encrypted zfs filesystem without preserving the encryption key

Tags: encryption, zfs

I want to copy an encrypted filesystem (z/enc/a) from one computer (source) to another, and have it inherit the encryption key from the parent filesystem of the target system.  I also want to compress it at the same time, and preserve snapshots.

I don't want to use raw send, because I don't want to preserve all properties and the encryption key.

This seems to work, where @first and @last are the first and last snapshots:

```
ssh source sudo zfs send z/enc/a@first | sudo zfs receive  -o compression=lz4 -x encryption z/enc/a
ssh source sudo zfs send z/enc/a@last -I @first | sudo zfs receive  -F z/enc/a
```

Is this the way to do it?

I checked the desired properties with:

`zfs list -r -t all -o name,compression,encryption,encryptionroot z/enc/a`

If the source filesystem were not encrypted, I could compress it and encrypt it with a single send/receive, like this:

```
ssh source sudo zfs send -R z/t/a@last | sudo zfs receive -F -o compression=lz4 -x encryption z/enc/a
```

But if I try this with an encrypted dataset, I get an error:

```
ssh source sudo zfs send -R z/enc/a@last | sudo zfs receive -F -o compression=lz4 -x encryption z/enc/a
cannot send z/enc/a@last: encrypted dataset z/enc/a may not be sent with properties without the raw flag
```

[This zfs issue](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10507) explains why a single send/receive does not work.

So the answer is probably that a two-step send/receive is needed, for now.